# How to get the last 3 characters of each word of a given string using short regex syntax?

Tags: python, string

I'm just starting with python. Below is my code to get the last 3 characters of each word in string. Is there a way to use a short regex syntax to get the same result?

```py
import re

names = 'steven thomas williams'

res = [x[0] for x in [[y.group() for y in re.finditer(r'.{3}$',z)] for z in names.split()]]

print(res) #['ven', 'mas', 'ams']
```

Comment: What about 2-length words ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### String slicing

Use `slicing` that is so much more efficient, and also you'll have only one for loop, instead of 3

```
names = 'steven thomas williams'
res = [z[-3:] for z in names.split()]
print(res)  # ['ven', 'mas', 'ams']
```

---

##### `re.search`

If you want to use `re`, use `re.search`

```
res = [re.search(r'.{3}$', z)[0] for z in names.split()]
```

---

#### Safety

Add `if len(z) >= 3` into the list comprenhension to filter too small words

```
res = [z[-3:] for z in names.split() if len(z) >= 3]
res = [re.search(r'.{3}$', z)[0] for z in names.split() if len(z) >= 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
names='steven thomas williams'
names=names.split(" ")
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(names[i][-3:])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).